# Element is not clickable at point (X, Y)

Tags: google-chrome, selenium, codeception

На странице присутствует `.top-panel`, которая привязывается к странице при скролле. Из-за этого происходит краш теста с ошибкой:

> Element is not clickable at point (X, Y)

Путем добавления `pointer-event` к панели проблема решается, но сама панель при этом ломается. Как решить такую проблему? Если не ошибаюсь есть возможность управлять стилями используя `Ruby\Java`, но в `codeception` такой возможности не обнаружил.

Answer (score 0):

Проблема была решена с помощью scrollTo без указания $offsetX и $offsetY:

`$I->scrollTo(['css' => '.checkout']);`

Полный Action с указанием оффсетов, выглядит так:

`$I->scrollTo(['css' => '.checkout'], X, Y);`